# Remove package from laravel-6.2 existing project an error occurred

Tags: laravel, package

Remove `pragmarx/tracker` package from laravel project by the following composer command

```
composer remove pragmarx/tracker
```

It's remove successfully but the below error shown. Even though `composer update` the error not fix.

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Middlewares\Tracker] does not exist.
```

How can I fix this error ? and which method to follow to completely remove any unused packages from laravel?

Comment: Most often `BindingResolutionExceptions` happen somewhere in the `AppServiceProvider` in the `register()` method. I'd start there.

Comment: how can I solve this? `public function register()
    {
        //empty
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on the [repo](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker):

> ## Installing
>
> Require the tracker package by executing the following command in your command line:
>
> ```
> composer require pragmarx/tracker
> ```
>
> Add the service provider to your `app/config/app.php`:
>
> ```php
> PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class,
> ```
>
> Add the alias to the facade on your `app/config/app.php`:
>
> ```php
> 'Tracker' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Facade',
> ```
>
> ### Publish tracker configuration:
>
> #### Laravel 4
>
> ```
> php artisan config:publish pragmarx/tracker
> ```
>
> #### Laravel 5
>
> ```
> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider"
> ```
>
> ### Enable the Middleware (Laravel 5)
>
> Open the newly published config file found at `app/config/tracker.php` and enable use_middleware:
>
> ```
> 'use_middleware' => true,
> ```
>
> ### Add the Middleware to Laravel Kernel (Laravel 5)
>
> Open the file `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add the following to your web middlewares:
>
> ```php
> \PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Middlewares\Tracker::class,
> ```
>
> ...

If you removed the package, make sure to

1. delete the `config/tracker.php` file
2. remove the line `PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class` from `config/app.php`
3. remove the line `'Tracker' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Facade',` from `config/app.php`
4. remove the line `\PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Middlewares\Tracker::class,` from `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Comment: Thanks solved, the problem is in `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.